# How to ask for a date?

Tags: english-to-german, pronunciation

How do you ask a woman out on a date in German? I.e. "would you like to go out sometime?"

Comment: welcome to German.SE. Please include your own research and where you struggle with it.

Comment: Welcome, T Krause. You may take a quick tour here: https://german.stackexchange.com/tour to see how to use this great website constructively.

Comment: I guess I do not know enough German to use this site correctly, so I will respectively remove myself from it. Cheers.

Comment: This question is neither about proofreading nor spellchecking or translation of individual texts. How to ask someone out is of upmost general interest and might be the best way to learn German. Where would one research and why shouldn't this be asked before the struggle begins? Closing questions for being off-topic seems to be the new sport. This question makes much more sense than the close votes.

Comment: @Olafant You are right in stating that this question should not be regarded as *off topic*, and I agree with you that in the last couple of months there have been a lot of ridiculous votes for closing as off topic. However, I think this question, after reopening, should be closed again as *opinion based*.

Comment: I voted to reopen. While the question can be interpreted as a translation request, it could equally well be seen as a request for some idiomatic phrases. Compare: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36426/whats-the-best-way-to-say-i-wasnt-listening-auf-deutsch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/polite-way-of-asking-someone-not-to-duz https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12031/how-do-you-ask-for-the-meaning-of-a-word-in-german/12035#12035

Comment: @DavidVogt: Yes. No. No - absolute no - own attempt or anything by the OP. Not even context to written "e.g." part - so it is even impossible to get the situation / the people to be asked. At least for me there are differences regarding age, sex, wealth/ social milieu.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm My recent impression is that the "no research" card is selectively played against questions by non-native speakers. For instance, no down votes, close votes or negative comments here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56107/spelling-lower-or-upper-case

Comment: @DavidVogt I agree that downvoting and closing questions has some arbitrariness. See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56058/nein-so-doch-nicht-no-not-at-all. There is a tag "german-to-english" which indicates that it is not unusual to ask such a question.

Answer (score 3):

Your example literally translated it is "Willst du irgendwann mal mit mir ausgehen?"
You could also say: "Wollen wir einmal etwas trinken gehen?", which is "Shall we have a drink one-time?". Or, if you don't have a drink in mind, but something else: "Wollen wir mal etwas miteinander unternehmen?", which is "Would you be up for doing something together sometime?".
Good luck!